# How to create a struct that creates a different amount of variables based on its input

Tags: c++, struct

I want to be able to have a basic struct that will only contain x amount of variables of the same type. This is so I can create child structs that can be called something else like a Vector struct or a Position struct. My question is there a way to vary how many variables that an instance of the `basic_struct` will create by a function input?

Say:

```
template<typename _Ty>
struct Vector2 : basic_struct<_Ty>(2) {/*vector code here*/}
```

and it will create a struct with 2 variables, while if I state:

```
template<typename _Ty>
struct Vector3 : basic_struct<_Ty>(3) {/*vector code here*/}
```

it will create a vector struct with three variables.

Thanks in advance for insights you can give me.

Comment: What do you mean by "in C or C++"?. Would Java or Python be acceptable?

Comment: @cigien Unfortunately no, my project is only in C/C++ at this stage and I don't really know Java or Python.

Comment: Ok, then remove the C++ tag from the question, and the title. Also note that C doesn't have templates. You'll pretty much have to rely on macros to do this for you.

Comment: @cigien sorry, yeah, I know C doesn't templates and I forgot to say above that the project is in C++ with aspects of C.

Comment: `basic_struct` really sounds like an array.  Why not just use an array?

Comment: Don't you want to use `std::vector<>`?

Comment: Please clarify whether the number of elements is known at compile-time or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [`std::array<T, N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).